# A different IP for a directory in a website

Tags: directory, subdomain, ip-address

I am not really sure how to phrase my question about this problem. What I want to ask is: I have the following scenario:
mydomain.com which has an ip address lets say aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
I created a directory:
mydomain.com\newDesign

What I want to know is, if I will be able to have a different ip address for this directory.
Which is something like that:
mydomain.com which has an ip address lets say aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
mydomain.com\newDesign which has an ip address lets say bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Apache virtual hosts.

You can set different Ips to any directory or subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

No. The closest you could do is ask the server at aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa to redirect queries in that subfolder to the server at bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb (or just send people to that server in the first place)